# Best way to pass a list with words to create a class in python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class named ShoppingList and I have a list of shopping lists. Each shopping list will always have 3 things: the first one is a fruit, the second one is a drink and the third one is an object.

```
shopping_lists = [['apple', 'wine', 'napkins'], 
                ['Avocado', 'soda', 'apron'], ['cherry', 'orange juice', 'knife']]
```

Then I created a new list called list_of_shopping_lists that will receive an array of the class ShoppingList using the information on shopping_lists from above.

```
list_of_shopping_lists = []
for my_list in shopping_lists:
    list_of_shopping_lists.append(shop_list.ShoppingList(
                                   my_list[0],my_list[1],my_list[2])
```

How can I make this code better without having to pass list[0], list[1], list[2]?

My class ShoppingList is the following:

```
class ShoppingList():
    """This Class provides a way to store shopping lists."""

    # Creating constructor
    def __init__(self, fruit, drink, obj):
        self._fruit = fruit
        self._drink = drink
        self._object = obj
```

Comment: Why not just pass the array into the class? And then do `self._fruit = arr[0]` etc. Also, using `list` as a name for a list is bad practice, as it overrides a built in type.

Comment: You can use `*` - awesome [unpack argument feature](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Like this: `shop_list.ShoppingList(*list)`.

Comment: `list_of_shopping_lists = [ShoppingList(*sub) for sub in shopping_lists]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this-

```
list_of_shopping_lists = []
for shoping_list in shopping_lists:
    list_of_shopping_lists.append(shop_list.ShoppingList(*shoping_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *Python*'s arguments unpacking:

```
shopping_lists = [['apple', 'wine', 'napkins'],
                  ['Avocado', 'soda', 'apron'], 
                  ['cherry', 'orange juice', 'knife']]

class ShoppingList():
    """This Class provides a way to store shopping lists."""

    # Creating constructor
    def __init__(self, fruit, drink, obj):
        self._fruit = fruit
        self._drink = drink
        self._object = obj


list_of_shopping_lists = [ShoppingList(*sh_list) for sh_list in shopping_lists]
print(list_of_shopping_lists)
```

Sample output:

```
[<__main__.ShoppingList object at 0x000000000420FF60>, <__main__.ShoppingList object at 0x0000000004F74E48>, <__main__.ShoppingList object at 0x0000000004F556D8>]
```

Also, avoid naming variables/attributes with `list` or `object` to prevent conflicts with Python's reserved names

https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists